# Помогите правильно настроить rewrite в nginx

Tags: php, nginx, чпу

Как перенаправить запрос типа `site.com/page1/block1/id/2` на `index.php?`?

В `index.php` `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` принимало значение `/page1/block1/id/2`

Comment: Вам надо только этот запрос перенаправлять или все подобные? Или вообще все запросы, кроме некоторых?

Answer (score 1):

Например так

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.

Comment: Комментарий не экспертный, а просто взят из документации к nginx.
в первом location используем проверку try_files - она пробует открыть файл который идет в $uri, если нету делает переход на /index.php с переданными параметрами.

Второй location берет все файлы оканчивающиеся на .php и переводит их на бэкенд (апач или еще кто-то) и также передает параметры в REQUEST_URI.